# How could I build a statistical map?

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I'm trying to figure out how to build a statistical map for my web app.  Here's what I've got:

I have a MySQL database of zip codes, and each zip code has latitude & longitude.
I have users who have declared what zip code they live in.
I even have a haversine query which will show how many users exist within, for example, 25 miles of a given latitude/longitude, based on their zip code.

My question is this:  Using this information, how could I approach building a statistical map for a web application using PHP?

I would be fine with using just a US map or even a North American map for now, but I'm just not sure how to build that map.  Some options I've considered:

1. Show a colored dot on the map, larger or smaller depending on the number of users near that location.  I'm not sure how to do this, though, especially if those dots were to overlap!
2. Show individual "pushpins" where the users are.  Seems like this could get out of hand if my user base grows significantly

So back to my question.  If I had 300 users in Dallas, 4,000 in NYC, 45 users in Detroit, 403 in Chicago... how would I be able to represent that on a map -- and also how would I draw that map in a web application built on PHP?

Comment: You want to plot your queried zip codes? Use Googe API, or a similar map API.

Comment: Thanks @Josh, I do want to plot queried zip codes but I also need to be able to show density at those locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to build a three-dimensional (probably even more dimensions) data display.

Your dimensions are:

- X-Location
- Y-Location
- The value at every location

This really does not define anything about the visual appearance, though.

A simple approach might be to calculate the absolute number of users per state and then color the state on the map according to some scale. You also might calculate the percentage of users living in a state compared to the absolute number and color that instead.

A different approach would be to put a dot for every user on the map, and if this dot was printed before, to change it's color instead, e.g. make it brighter.

In the end, it really depends on what your actual data is and if your approach on visualizing it displays some significant information - but this can only be confirmend after you see it.

Comment: I think your second approach, where the dot is printed and then gets brighter if it's printed again, is along the lines I'm looking for.  Since posting this, I'm trying to learn about putting transparent tiles on top of google maps and it sounds like I may be able to do something along the lines of what you mentioned here

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking for a web application have you considered Google Maps. Factor 1. can be implemented using the MarkerClusterer library. A [DEMO](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html) showing this. The data from your database can be loaded using AJAX.

Comment: Actually yes I am considering Google Maps.  In fact thanks to Ceejayoz's comment above, I was able to find this: http://blog.gmapify.fr/index.php?category=5  I'm not sure if it'll work for me yet, but that's pretty close to what I'm trying to do.